# Xpath with XMLTABLE

Tags: sql, oracle, xpath, oracle12c

Using this XML :

```
<attrs>
    <attr multiple="true" name="LETTER">
        <string>A</string>
        <string>B</string>
        <string>C</string>
        <string>D</string>
    </attr>
    <attr multiple="true" name="NUMBER">
        <string>1</string>
        <string>2</string>
        <string>3</string>
        <string>4</string>
    </attr>
    ...
</attrs>
```

I'm trying to have this result using XMLTABLE :

```
+------+--------+--------+
| REF  | LETTER | NUMBER |
+------+--------+--------+
| REF1 | A      |      1 |
| REF1 | B      |      2 |
| REF1 | C      |      3 |
| ...  | ...    |    ... |
+------+--------+--------+
```

I'm very bad with Xpath, i'm stuck here but this concat all values :

```
XMLTABLE('/attrs'
    PASSING XMLTYPE(XML)
    COLUMNS LETTER VARCHAR2(50) PATH 'attr[@name="LETTER"]',
            NUMBER VARCHAR2(50) PATH 'attr[@name="NUMBER"]'
) X
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please always state the exact version of the database engine you're using. (There should be a tag for that, adding the tag would be enough.)

Comment: sorry, i've jus added the oracle12c tag

Comment: Do you have a fixed number of `string` elements (easier) or is the number dynamic (more difficult;)

Answer (score 2):

Here the solution of the simpler case that expects fixed number of the `string` elements.

In the first step to get the data in a *transposed* form in a table

```
create table tab as 
with doc as (
select 
xmltype(q'{<attrs>
    <attr multiple="true" name="LETTER">
        <string>A</string>
        <string>B</string>
        <string>C</string>
        <string>D</string>
    </attr>
    <attr multiple="true" name="NUMBER">
        <string>1</string>
        <string>2</string>
        <string>3</string>
        <string>4</string>
    </attr>
    ...
</attrs>}') as doc from  DUAL)
select x.* from doc,
         XMLTable(
          'for $i in /attrs/attr    
           return $i'
          passing  (doc.doc)
          columns
                 col_name varchar2(10) path '//attr/@name',
                 s1 varchar2(10) path '//string[1]',
                 s2 varchar2(10) path '//string[2]',
                 s3 varchar2(10) path '//string[3]',
                 s4 varchar2(10) path '//string[4]'
                  ) x
;

COL_NAME   S1         S2         S3         S4        
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
LETTER     A          B          C          D         
NUMBER     1          2          3          4
```

This is nearly what you expects, but must be transposed.  I'm sure there is a simple approach, but this query works. Apply `UNPIVOT` than `PIVOT` followed with column rename.

```
with q1 as ( 
select * from tab 
UNPIVOT (
     x 
    FOR src 
    IN (
        s1 AS 'X', 
        s2 AS 'Y',
        s3 as 'Z',
        s4 as 'U'
    )
)),
q2 as (
select * from q1
PIVOT (max(x) "VAL"  for (col_name) in 
('LETTER' as "LETTER",
'NUMBER' as "NUMBER")
))
select LETTER_VAL as "LETTER", NUMBER_VAL as "NUMBER"
from q2
order by 1;
```

**Result of UNPIVOT**

```
COL_NAME   S X         
---------- - ----------
LETTER     X A         
LETTER     Y B         
LETTER     Z C         
LETTER     U D         
NUMBER     X 1         
NUMBER     Y 2         
NUMBER     Z 3         
NUMBER     U 4
```

**Result of PIVOT**

```
S LETTER_VAL NUMBER_VAL
- ---------- ----------
X A          1         
Y B          2         
Z C          3         
U D          4
```

**Final Result**

```
LETTER     NUMBER    
---------- ----------
A          1         
B          2         
C          3         
D          4
```

Comment: Thank you so much Marmite Bomber it's working :) very tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Marmite Bomber, it's very tricky.

Here is the request working I use :

```
WITH Q1 AS (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT X.*
        FROM PRODUCT P,
        XMLTABLE('for $i in /attrs/attr return $i'
            PASSING XMLTYPE(P.XML)
            COLUMNS ATTRIBUTENAME VARCHAR2(50) PATH '//@name',
                    S1 VARCHAR2(50) path '//string[1]',
                    S2 VARCHAR2(50) path '//string[2]',
                    S3 VARCHAR2(50) path '//string[3]',
                    S4 VARCHAR2(50) path '//string[4]',
                    S5 VARCHAR2(50) path '//string[5]',
                    S6 VARCHAR2(50) path '//string[6]',
                    S7 VARCHAR2(50) path '//string[7]',
                    S8 VARCHAR2(50) path '//string[8]',
                    S9 VARCHAR2(50) path '//string[9]',
                    S10 VARCHAR2(50) path '//string[10]'
        ) X
        WHERE X.ATTRIBUTENAME IN ('LETTER', 'NUMBER')
        AND P.REF = 'REF1')
    UNPIVOT (
        X
        FOR SRC 
        IN (
            S1 AS 'Q', 
            S2 AS 'R',
            S3 as 'S',
            S4 as 'T',
            S5 as 'U',
            S6 as 'V',
            S7 as 'W',
            S8 as 'X',
            S9 as 'Y',
            S10 as 'Z'
        )
    )
), Q2 AS (
    SELECT * FROM Q1
    PIVOT (
        MAX(X) "VAL" 
        FOR (ATTRIBUTENAME)
        IN (
            'LETTER' as "LETTER",
            'NUMBER' as "NUMBER"
        )
    )
) SELECT LETTER_VAL AS "LETTER", NUMBER_VAL AS "NUMBER"
FROM Q2
ORDER BY 1;
```